# Dapper with dynamic variables won't work without mapping. This breaks SQL. How to use Dapper with bigger SQL query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, dapper

Let say that I had a stored proc in MS SQL. Now I have moved to MySQL and I want to keep all SQL queries inside of C# asp.net core app.

The issue starts with bigger queries where can be SQL dynamic internal variables.

I.e.
 `Select @TypeId := TypeId, @StartDate := StartDate
  From Test_test
  Where Id = @Id`

In this example @Id supposed to be mapped by Dapper (this variable is passed from a DAL to MySQL database), however @TypeId and @StartId shouldn't be mapped.

1. There is many more dynamic variables created only for SQL query
2. Mapping null will break query i.e. here is results from SQL

   `NULL := StartDate` instead of `@StartDate := StartDate`

How can I use dapper with SQL queries where query is creating dynamically variables that shouldn't be mapped by Dapper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem at all with using SQL variables in a query with Dapper as long as you include `AllowUserVariables=true` in your connection string. This allows the client library to "ignore" `@TypeId` and `@StartDate` in your SQL and not require them to be specified in the `MySqlCommand.Parameters` collection.

As long as you don't include properties with those names in the anonymous object you pass to Dapper (i.e., don't do `new { StartDate = DateTime.Now, TypeId = 1 }`), Dapper won't create any parameters with those names, won't map any values to them, and will pass the SQL through to MySQL Server to be evaluated as server-side variables.

Comment: Thank you, exactly this was missing ! So it wasn't a dapper after all.